# Does Salesforce allow encryption of outgoing mail or do I need to set up an email relay?

Tags: email

Can anyone tell me if Salesforce allows encryption of outgoing mail or do I need to set up an email relay?

Comment: Encryption of the contents, like PGP, or at the transportation layer, like TLS or SSL?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, salesforce.com prefers to encrypt email transmissions with TLS when possible (by default). You can control this in Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability. In fact, you have to go out of your way to disable TLS entirely, since there's no harm in upgrading when possible.